# How to get particular field in splunk search for a nested JSON event

Tags: json, regex, splunk

I am trying to extract this `userid` (which is part of `applicationTags`) field in Splunk.

Can someone please help.

Json:

```
json
{ [-]
   allocatedMB: -1
   allocatedMemorySeconds: 1546332
   allocatedVCores: -1
   allocatedVcoreSeconds: 273
   applicationId: application_1658075295053_0071
   applicationTags: [ [-]
     hive_20220718142121_632022dc-9399-4034-a45d-08042dfb4367
     userid=rajani
   ]
   attributes: { [-]
     diagnostics: Session stats:submittedDAGs=1, successfulDAGs=1, failedDAGs=0, killedDAGs=0

   }
   endTime: 2022-07-18T14:23:52.384Z
   mr2AppInformation: { [-]
   }
   name: HIVE-907b6fd3-aa12-4136-af66-9787fdec52c5
   pool: xxx
   progress: 100
   runningContainers: -1
   startTime: 2022-07-18T14:21:23.254Z
   state: FINISHED
   user: hive
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spath command of splunk:

```
... | spath output=myfield path=applicationTags{}.userid
```

More information and examples can be found in the official documentation: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Spath

Answer (score -1):

There are at least two approaches you can use

If your sourcetype's JSON is not being parsed properly by Splunk, this [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) will pull it for you:

```
| rex field=_raw "userid=(?<userid>\w+)"
```

If it *is* being parsed properly, then you can probably get it by [a](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rename) variation on the theme of:

```
| rename applicationTags{}.userid as userid
```

To get a full listing of the fields Splunk knows about for this sourcetype, use [`fieldsummary`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/fieldsummary). Eg:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp
| fieldsummary
| fields field values
```